# classic asp async sql execution

Tags: asp-classic

I have a classic asp application (ASP 3.0 running on Windows 2000/IIS 5.0) which allows users to write custom SQL queries to fetch data from the database (Oracle 10g), more like SQL Developer. Sometimes users write complex queries which runs indefinitely, though the user would click the back button to go back to previous page, the query might still run on the database. Now users are requesting they be given a functionality to kill the query on a click of a button.

I am beginner in asp, so I am not sure if this is possible in asp. We are using ADODB.RecordSet object to fetch the data using RecordSet.Open and RecordSet.GetRows. Please advise if this is achievable in classic asp.

```
Set connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connection.Open DATA_SOURCE, LOGON_ID, PASSWORD
Set resultset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Dim sql
sql="select sysdate from dual"
resultset.Open sql, connection 
Dim DBData
DBData = resultset.GetRows(NUMROWS)
resultset.close
connection.close
Set resultset = Nothing
Set connection = Nothing
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you could try to wrap database functions in a `Class` and close the connection in `Private Sub Class_Terminate`.

Comment: You need to call the Connection.Cancel method. Other option would be to use transactions and call Connection.RollbackTrans. If the queries are running as a sort of background process... you're only option would be to call Session.abandon (take note that this will  destroy ALL the users session variables and objects... not just one database query)

Comment: Is sysdate a field. Because there is no such keyword in sql

Comment: @polin `sysdate` is a built-in function in oracle; [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
arrayRs = resultset.GetRows()
if arrayRs(0,0)<> "" then
response.write(arrayRs(0,0))
end if
```

Or you can try a loop when you are fetching more than one field